# Is it possible for Javascript to generate a DOM html that is unextractable by Cheerio?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cheerio

I am trying to extract the price from this webpage: https://www.allbirds.com/products/mens-wool-runner-up-mizzles-natural-grey?size=13

I narrowed it down to these divs:

```
<div class="jsx-3947815802 Container">
<div class="jsx-526902087 Grid">
<div class="jsx-2943457050 Grid__cell Grid__cell--small-12 Grid__cell--medium-7 Grid__cell--large-up-8">...
```

The jsx-{random_number} for the class names is suspicious to me. They seem generated on the fly. The price I need is inside divs like these. However, these don't exist in the page source and or the cheerio object I am using during runtime. It just disappears.

How common is this technique? It seems like a pretty good way to stop web scrapers. How do I get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those classes are random, it might be annoying, but it's not a deal-breaker, because the *other* classes look to be static.

For example, the element that includes the price looks something like:

```
<p class="jsx-3188494938 Paragraph PdpMasterProductDetails__paragraph">$135</p>
```

The `PdpMasterProductDetails__paragraph` does not change. So, you can retrieve the text by using that as a selector:

```
$('.PdpMasterProductDetails__paragraph').text()
```

You can also retrieve the price from a meta tag:

```
<meta property="og:price:amount" content="135">
```

which can be selected via the selector string:

```
meta[property="og:price:amount"]
```

Comment: I cannot believe I did not see the metatag for amount in the page source. Thank you so much for pointing that out lol

Answer (score 0):

> How common is this technique?

Very.

Building websites as Single Page Applications with tools like React is very common.

> It seems like a pretty good way to stop web scrapers.

It isn't.

> How do I get around it?

Hit the web service the React code fetches the raw data from directly. It's easily discoverable via the Network tab in the browser's developer tools.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did what you said and found the raw data. However, I would like a more general approach. I started looking into Puppeteer since it loads in everything first instead of Cheerio. Do you recommend this approach?

Comment: No. The general approach I recommend is to reverse engineer the API. It is massively more efficient and easier.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Is there a universal API all these sites will use?

Comment: No, there's nothing universal about any of this. He means it's easier to get the data from the xhrs than to parse it out of a fully loaded browser context, which is probably more true for  him or me than it is for you.